# Unable to create track bar in control panel. Example code is not working

Tags: c++, opencv

**Problem:**

I have tried to example code from the official OpenCV website. Click
[here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html)
The code :

```
createTrackbar( "track2", NULL, &value2, 255, NULL);
```

seems to create a problem. My vscode complain about my second argument, NULL.

> more than one constructor applies to convert from "long" to "cv::String": -- function "cv::String::String(const char *s)" -- function "cv::String::String(int)"

But on the website, it said

> To attach a trackbar [in control panel], the window name parameter must be NULL.

However, I can still compile this, but it gives me run time error

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>     what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
>   Aborted (core dumped)

**Background:**
I am using Ubuntu 18.XX LTS and using OpenCV 4.1.0-dev

**Code**

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

void callbackButton0(int state, void *userdata){//Do nothing, just test};
void callbackButton1(int state, void *userdata){//Do nothing, just test};
void callbackButton2(int state, void *userdata){//Do nothing, just test};
void on_mouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *userdata){
    //Do nothing, just test
};

/*-------------------------- Entry point ----------------------------- */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int value = 50;
    int value2 = 0;
    cv::namedWindow("main1",cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::namedWindow("main2",cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::createTrackbar( "track1", "main1", &value, 255,  NULL);
    cv::String nameb1 = "button1";
    cv::String nameb2 = "button2";
    cv::createButton(nameb1,callbackButton0,&nameb1,cv::QT_CHECKBOX,1);
    cv::createButton(nameb2,callbackButton0,NULL,cv::QT_CHECKBOX,0);

    /* ----------- The problem is here. ----------*/
    cv::createTrackbar( "track2", NULL, &value2, 255, NULL); 

    cv::createButton("button5",callbackButton1,NULL,cv::QT_RADIOBOX,0);
    cv::createButton("button6",callbackButton2,NULL,cv::QT_RADIOBOX,1);
    cv::setMouseCallback( "main2",on_mouse,NULL );
    cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("/home/mhyip/Pictures/thumbnail.jpeg");
    cv::VideoCapture video;
    video.open("/home/mhyip/Videos/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4");
    cv::Mat img2,img3;
    while( cv::waitKey(30) != 27 )
    {
        img1.convertTo(img2,-1,1,value);
        video >> img3;
        imshow("main1",img2);
        imshow("main2",img3);
    }
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
/*-------------------------- Entry point end----------------------------- */
```

**Expected result**
I just want to have the same result as in the official website, which there is a trackbar in the controll panel.

Thank you.

Comment: Does anything different happen when you pass a `nullptr` instead? That way overloads taking a `long` wont be considered.

Comment: Sorry `nullptr` does not work. But `" "` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, believe this is the overload you should be using:

> C++: int createTrackbar(const string& trackbarname, const string& winname, int* value, int count, TrackbarCallback onChange=0, void* userdata=0)

Also, note:

> [Qt Backend Only] winname can be empty (or NULL) if the trackbar should be attached to the control panel.

So try this:

```
cv::createTrackbar( "track2", "", &value2, 255);
```

Rational: 
For the `C++` API you are supposed to pass in an empty string, not `NULL`. What was happening is since you used `NULL`, which is mapped to the value 0, you were actually calling the `cv::string` constructor overload which takes a `const char*` in its `ctor`.

The 0 was being implicitly converted. The `cv::string ctor` was then throwing an exception because '0' is not a valid `pointer` to a `C style string`. Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` to avoid any weird implicit conversions. This will cause a compile time error instead of a runtime error.

Comment: It works. But why? As you said, it can be NULL. So pass NULL should work. Right?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation of what was happening.